# Grid column line using Display property GRID

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here,in this code I want to understand what does the grid-column-start and grid-column-end specify ?

This is the HTML part of my code.

```
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="grid-item1">1</div>
<div class="grid-item2">2</div>
<div class="grid-item3">3</div>  
<div class="grid-item3">4</div>
<div class="grid-item5">5</div>
<div class="grid-item6">6</div>  
<div class="grid-item7">7</div>
<div class="grid-item8">8</div>
<div class="grid-item9">9</div>
```

This is the CSS part of my code.

```
.grid-container 
 {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
 grid-gap : 50px;
 background-color: black;
 padding: 10px;
 }
 div 
 {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 }
.grid-item1
{
grid-column-start : 1 ;
grid-column-end : 3;
}
```

[image: This is the output of the code]
This is the output of the code.
So, what does grid-column-end specify here ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end

Comment: Go read this pages [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Hope it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grid-column-start` property defines on which column-line the item will start.
and

The `grid-column-end` property defines how many columns an item will span, or on which column-line the item will end.

Please have a look of this below two examples: 1-[grid-column-start](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-column-start.asp) 2-[grid-column-end](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-column-end.asp)

Answer (score 0):

So what it basically does is, When you give `grid-column-start : 1| grid-column-end : 3`. The column will start from the position one and span till the column 3.

The short-hand method of this will be `grid-column: 1 / 3;` Which starts from 1 and end at the column 3 which will make other columns to move.

See examples here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what **grid-template-column** property does, check Chrome DevTools and inspect "grid-item1". Shorter method is: `grid-column: 1/3;` - div spans across two columns; starting at first line and finishing at third --> | col | col |
Instead of using pixels in *grid-template-columns* property, I suggest using this to avoid non-responsiveness: 
`grid-template-columns: repeat(12/1fr);` 
or 
`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr);`